# FlowPlayer - Getting a Download popup link after adding wmmode: 'opaque'

Tags: jquery, video, flowplayer

After adding the wmode: 'opaque' to the FlowPlayer, I'm getting the FireFox download popup and its asking me if I want to save the .flv file. The video actually still plays.

My markup:

```
<a href="command page.flv" style="display:block;width:254px;height:163px;" id="player"></a>
```

My FlowPlayer Script:

```
flowplayer("player", {src: '/swf/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.7.swf', wmode: 'opaque'},  {
          plugins: {
            controls: {
              url: 'flowplayer.controls-3.2.5.swf',

              autoHide: false,
              buttonColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)',
              buttonOverColor: '#000000',
              backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
              backgroundGradient: 'medium',
              height: '20px',
              sliderColor: '#FFFFFF',

              sliderBorder: '1px solid #808080',
              volumeSliderColor: '#FFFFFF',
              volumeBorder: '1px solid #808080',

              // which buttons are visible and which are not?
              play:true,
              volume:true,
              mute:true,
              time:false,
              stop:false,
              playlist:false,
              fullscreen:true,

              timeColor: '#000000',
              durationColor: '#535353'
            }
          },
          logo: {
            url: 'splash.jpg',
            fullscreenOnly: false,
            zIndex:0,
            top: '44%',
            left: '50%'
          },
          clip: {

            // these two configuration variables does the trick
            autoPlay: false,
            autoBuffering: false
          }
});
```

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the  tag to a  tag and that fixed the problem.